# Entity Framework Mapping, different property name

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I have a database field called `abCode`, that I want to map to a property called `statusCode` in the objectlayer. What changes are needed to the msl, csdl, ssdl and object layer to acomplish this?

Here are the relevent (I think) parts of the files:

In msl:

```
<ScalarProperty Name="abCode" ColumnName="abCode" />
```

In csdl:

```
<Property Name="abCode" Type="Int32" />
```

In ssdl:

```
<Property Name="ParentId" Type="int" />
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through pure trial and error the changes needed are:

In msl:

```
<ScalarProperty Name="statusCode " ColumnName="abCode" />
```

In csdl:

```
<Property Name="statusCode " Type="Int32" />
```

And in the objectlayer, the private property for `abCode` changed to `StatusCode`.